# How do you solve logarithmic equations like this one?

Tags: logarithms

How do you solve
$$3\log(x-15)=\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^x?$$
The solution is approximately $16$. How would you solve a logarithmic equation with an solution approximately equal to a number without using a graphing calculator?

Comment: Once upon a time, men didn't have cellphones but were smart. They knew a continuous function that changes sign should intersect the x-axis somewhere in between. They would notice that if you make $x=16$ the left hand side is zero while the right hand side stays above zero. They would then put $x=17$ and notice the left hand side is $3\log(2)=\log(8)>1$, while $1/4^{17}<1$.

Comment: Men did not have cellphones? You are joking, right?

Comment: No, it is true. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone#History)

Comment: Only women had cell phones then.

Comment: But really, it seems most unlikely to have a nice answer at all. Comparing a logarithm to an exponential will not generally turn out well, and the logarithm of a sum does not make it any prettier.

Comment: This type of logarithmic and/or exponential equations can be expressed analytically in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). If you want, I could post a detailed answer later, showing how this is done.

Comment: @dfeuer Men not having cellphones doesn't imply women having cellphones. $(M\nsubseteq C)\nRightarrow(M^{c}\subset C)$.

Comment: @Lucian I would like to see the solution using Lambert function. To me, this case seems quite non-trivial for Lambert function.

Comment: @pisoir: You're right. This one can't even be expressed in terms of Lambert's function, since it's the equivalent of $(\ln t)e^t=a$, as opposed to $te^t=a$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what base of logs you are using.  The approach will be the same in any case-I will assume natural logs.  We must have $x \gt 15$ or the logarithm is not defined.  In that case, the right side will be very small and positive.  We need $x \gt 16$ to make the left side positive.  Define $a=x-16$, where we expect $a$ to be very small, so we will use the first term of the Taylor series.
$$3 \log (x-15)=\left(\frac 14\right)^{\!x}\\
3 \log (1+a)=\left(\frac 14\right)^{\!16+a}\\
3\cdot 4^{16}a=4^{-a}$$  This shows $a \approx \frac 1{3\cdot 4^{16}}$ with both sides very close to $1$, so $x \approx 16+\frac 1{3\cdot 4^{16}}$.

Comment: @dfeuer:  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that for $x>10$ the right hand side is smaller than $1/1000000,$ so you are essentially solving for $LHS = 0.$ There is no general method if you are not so lucky.

Comment: And the _left_ hand side doesn't even exist for $x\le 15$ ...